# How can I secure with JWT the endpoints generated with the Loopback v4 REST CRUD model endpoints generator

Tags: authentication, jwt, generator, crud, loopback4

I have generated a Loopback 4 REST API application for CRUD operations against a relational DB, using the REST CRUD model endpoints generator available in Loopback 4:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Creating-crud-rest-apis.html

Now I trying to secure the endpoints, according to this: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html I should add an authenticate decoration to the class exports in the controller definitions. But in my case there is no such definition in my application, besides the one for the user endpoint.

How can I secure with JWT the endpoints generated with the Loopback v4 REST CRUD model endpoints generator?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: We are running into the same issue, were you ever able to find an answer to this one?

Comment: Hi, have a look at the following:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-overview.html

https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback4-example-shopping#authentication

Comment: Did it work, I mean auth with JWT

Comment: Nope, no can do. I am not that skilled in modifying the code and I cannot do a rewrite of the part of the Loopback v4 REST CRUD model generator.